# Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined OR how to include javascript in Twig

Tags: javascript, symfony

In my Symfony project I try to make use of Chartjs.org's javascript.

I put the chart.js file right there where all other javascript files are located and in javascript.html I include the file so that it is available across the project.

```
<script src="assets/js/chart.js"></script>
```

In my twig template I try to instantiate Chart like this:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);
</script>
```

This throws an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined

What am I missing?

**The answer:**

```
{% javascripts '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

More details: http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Comment: Are you sure the file is being loaded? Is it included before you try to use it?

Comment: When you press F12 in Firefox or chrome you can see what files failed to load (dev tools). Maybe the file is loaded but you call new Chart before the script that defines the chart is loaded.

Comment: @HMR I just found out that the file actually isn't loaded. So, in Symfony2 how would you go about making the script available across the whole project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the question where to put your scripts, maybe this will work:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/propuestas_public.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets

> The asset function's main purpose is to make your application more
>   portable. If your application lives at the root of your host (e.g.
>   http://example.com), then the rendered paths should be
>   /images/logo.png. But if your application lives in a subdirectory
>   (e.g. http://example.com/my_app), each asset path should render with
>   the subdirectory (e.g. /my_app/images/logo.png). The asset function
>   takes care of this by determining how your application is being used
>   and generating the correct paths accordingly.
>
> Additionally, if you use the asset function, Symfony can automatically
>   append a query string to your asset, in order to guarantee that
>   updated static assets won't be cached when deployed. For example,
>   /images/logo.png might look like /images/logo.png?v2. For more
>   information, see the assets_version configuration option.